# How to store user's screen name in MySql?

Tags: javascript, php, mysql, database-design

I have a registration form, where the users can enter some information about themselves. I'm not fond of required fields myself, so the form is very liberal.
Thus, there is a function to generate a screen name for the user.
The user can have a login, a full name (like John Doe), a nickname (like C0olH}{kkr) or any combination of three. The [login] field is optional, because the user may choose registration via a social network instead.
So, the idea behind the generation of the screen name for the user is this

JavaScript:

```
var nickname = $('#nickname');
var fullname = $('#fullname');
var screen_name = $('#screen-name');
if (nickname.val() && fullname.val()) {
    screen_name.val(fullname.val()+" ("+nickname.val()+")");
} else {
    screen_name.val(nickname.val() || fullname.val() || $('#login').val());
}
```

HTML:

```
<p>
  <label for="login"><span><?= _("Login") ?></span><span class="asterix" style="color:red"> *</span></label>
  <input type="text" name="login" id="login" value="111" class="textinput" required/>
</p>
<p>
  <label for="fullname"><span><?= _("Full name") ?></span></label>
  <input type="text" name="fullname" id="fullname" value="" class="textinput"/>
</p>
<p>
  <label for="nickname"><span><?= _("Nickname") ?></span></label>
  <input type="text" name="nickname" id="nickname" value="" class="textinput"/>
  <input type="hidden" name="screen_name" id="screen-name" value="" />
</p>
```

Then I store the screen_name field via PHP:

```
        $query_user_insert = $this->db_connection->prepare('INSERT INTO users (login, fullname, nickname, screen_name) VALUES(:login, :fullname, :nickname, :screen_name)');
        $query_user_insert->bindValue(':login', $login, PDO::PARAM_STR);
        $query_user_insert->bindValue(':fullname', $fullname, PDO::PARAM_STR);
        $query_user_insert->bindValue(':nickname', $nickname, PDO::PARAM_STR);                  
        $query_user_insert->bindValue(':screen_name', $screen_name, PDO::PARAM_STR);
```

The question is:

Is the above method OK? On one hand, the table "users" might not conform an SQL normal form because the "screen_name" field is redundant. On the other hand, it might be a performance issue when someone wants to get to search through users and see their screen names, this will happen very often.

Comment: you're worrying too much. it's only redundant at a conceptual level, and only for those users who choose to not set a custom screen name. if you don't store something in there, you'd need some OTHER field to indicate "this user has no scree name", or hacks like setting the screenname field to null and lots of special-case query/php code to handle "Is the field null? then replace with real name".

Comment: Marc, the point is there is NO screen_name field in the form. There is login, there is fullname and there is nickname. That's all. All other fields are not related to user's name or its variants.